# Ghostscript loses emdash characters and replaces with hyphens

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

When I run a PDF which was originally created with LibreOffice on Linux, through ghostscript 9.19 on OSX, to produce another (flattened) PDF, the output is perfect except for one problem.  All emdashes in the entire document have been replaced with a standard hyphen (awkwardly followed by half of a space.)  Oddly enough, if I highlight the resulting "hyphen+space", my context menu shows that I've selected an emdash, so the underlying text is still an emdash, it is just rendering the wrong glyph.

I can reproduce this on multiple documents from the same source, and I'm assuming there's a setting or switch somewhere that can help resolve this.

I don't know whether the font used makes a difference, but for the sake of reference, the body text of my document is set in Arno Pro.  When I use a modern version of LibreOffice on OS X to make a sample document also containing an emdash in Arno Pro, the same problem is not exhibited, so it seems to be specific to the software which originally made these PDF files.

These PDFs are of legacy projects that I am not set-up to re-produce at this time, so I need to prepare them for reprinting using the existing files.

How do I retain emdash glyphs when running a command such as the following?

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-sColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \ 
-dAutoFilterColorImages=true -dAutoFilterGrayImages=true \ 
-sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

I can add an example of the input PDF to this question if needed.

Comment: Upon closer investigation, I realize it isn't rendering as a regular hyphen followed by a space, but it seems more like an endash or minus sign followed by a space.  In other words, the dash is occupying half of the distance the emdash is supposed to occupy, and the remaining half of the distance is white space.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the PDF file it isn't possible to give you an answer. Most likely the font isn't embedded, or if it is embedded doesn't have an emdash glyph.

Copy and paste uses the ToUnicode CMap, so it isn't dependent on the font. Its simply a list of character codes and the Unicode code point associated with each, when using a given font.

Note that this doesn't mean 'the underlying text is still an emdash'. The ToUnicode information is utterly separate from the font end of things, it is effectively metadata and bears no real relation to the font or rendering.

Put the file on DropBox and post the URL and someone can look into it. I'll be on vacation for the next few days though, but maybe someone else will look.

Note that in PDF you don't necessarily specify characters and positions as a list of consecutive characters; you can specify the position of each individually, or you can specify widths which override the width in the font, etc. So there almost certainly is only one glyph, the 'white space' you refer to is probably just that, white space, its not another glyph.

I should also point out (I do this a lot) that Ghostscript never 'flattens', concatenates, merges, or anything similar operation on PDF files. WHen using Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device the original input (in whatever format) is fully interpreted into graphics marking operations, and sent tot eh device. The device executes the marking operations; in the case of a rendering device, it scan-converts and writes to a bitmap. In the case of pdfwrite, it creates PDF operators.

The result of this is that the output PDF file bears no relation to the input PDF, other than its visual appearance.

You also don't say which version of Ghostscript you are using....